# Can I trust a hash commit for integrity of the entire repository?

Tags: hash, integrity, git

Sometimes there's no tar release for some repo in github, and the download as zip button only generates a random zip with random hash. So, in my Dockerfile, I want to clone a repo but be able to check against some hash to prevent tampering.

If I do

```
git clone https://github.com/repo/repo && git checkout hash
```

then can I trust that there's no way for the repo owner to replace that specific commit with another version of the code with some malware?

In other words, does a commit hash hashes everything up to that commit, or it's just a hash of the diff of the commit?